# Where can I find python code for SVM that use multiple feature data?

Tags: svm, image-classification, libsvm

I am trying do an Image Classification where each sample of training data contains data of the current pixel with the 8 surrounding ones.

Where can I find examples of SVM, in python, that use 5 or more features in training?

Answer (score 1):

By modifying the $2$-dimensional example in [scikit Documentation about SVM](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html), we have this $5$ dimensional example.

```
from sklearn import svm
X = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
y = [0, 1]
clf = svm.SVC()
clf.fit(X, y)  
print(clf.predict([[2., 2., 2., 2., 2.], [-1 for i in range(5)]]))
```

You can read more about the parameters option of SVC [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html#sklearn.svm.SVC)